# Functor instance for (newtype Mu f = InF {outF :: f (Mu f)})

Tags: haskell, functor

This has me stumped. How do you write a Functor instance for `newtype Mu f = InF {outF :: f (Mu f)}`

Comment: If you do `newtype Mu f a = InF { outF :: f (Mu f a) }`, then `instance Functor f => Functor (Mu f)` is possible. This is just `Free` without the `Pure` constructor, though.

Comment: Check https://github.com/ekmett/recursion-schemes/pull/23 for musings around this very problem.

Comment: For interested, this is an exercise from Chapter 16. Functors of *Haskell Programming from First Principles*.

Answer (score 9):

You can't. In order to define an instance `Functor c` for some `c`, `c` must be of the kind `* -> *`. So in your case, `Mu` should have been of that kind, which means that its argument `f` must have been of the kind `*`. But clearly this is not the case, as you are applying `f` to something else (to `Mu f`).

To put it more simply, if `Mu` was a functor, you could use `fmap` on values of type `Mu f` for any `f`. But this would have allowed you to change the type parameter to any other type, e.g., by applying the function `fmap (const (0 :: Int))` to any `Mu f` value, it would have to return a `Mu Int` value. But you can not form such a value because the `outF` of that value would have had type `Int (Mu Int)` which does not make sense.

Comment: I'd add the explicit kind signature `Mu :: (* -> *) -> *` to stress that it is not the one required by `Functor` (`* -> *` as mentioned above), so we get a kind error.

Answer (score 5):

redneb gives a good explanation of why `Mu` cannot be a regular `Functor` but you can implement a sort of functor-like mapping operation for `Mu` as

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype Mu f = InF {outF :: f (Mu f)}

mumap :: Functor f => (forall a. f a -> g a) -> Mu f -> Mu g
mumap f (InF m) = InF $ f $ fmap (mumap f) m
```

Though I'm not sure how useful it would be in your case. :)

Comment: IOW `Mu` is a functor from the category of type constructors `* -> *` (whose morphisms are natural transformations `forall x. f x -> g x`) to the category of Haskell types `*` and functions

Answer (score 0):

A slight re-phrasing of `Mu`, different from user2297560's, is sufficient to admit a Functor instance for Mu:

```
-- Natural transformations
type g ~> h = forall a. g a -> h a

class HFunctor f where
  ffmap :: Functor g => (a -> b) -> f g a -> f g b
  hfmap :: (Functor g, Functor h) => (g ~> h) -> (f g ~> f h)

newtype Mu f a = In { unIn :: f (Mu f) a }

instance HFunctor f => Functor (Mu f) where
  fmap f (In r) = In (ffmap f r)
```

This formulation comes from Patricia and Neil's paper [Haskell Programming with Nested Types: A Principled Approach](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3cb7/d5c74497fc23d813de4d121c0796eb82962b.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

As redneb describes, a functor instance must have kind `* -> *`, which prohibits `Mu` from being a functor, given that its argument `f` is applied to an argument, in `f (Mu f)`.

Here's a breakdown the various kinds involved.

---

First, the new type being created, after all applied arguments, must have kind `*`. Therefore:

`Mu f` must have kind `*`.

Second, what `Mu f` is set equal to must also have that same kind. That is,

`InF { outF :: f (Mu f) }` must have kind `*`.

Third, `outF` is a function, and therefore must return a fully-realized type, whether parameterized or concrete,
i.e. of kind `*`. `f (Mu f)` is its return type. So

`f (Mu f)` must have kind `*`.

Finally, `f` is an applied kind, since it appears in `f (Mu f)`.
In other words, it has kind `f_argument_kind -> f_result_kind` for some kind `f_argument_kind`
and some kind `f_result_kind`.
And furthermore, `f (Mu f)` tells us the kinds of both `f_argument_kind` and `f_result_kind`.
That is, `f_argument_kind` matches `Mu f`'s kind (`*`) and `f_result_kind` matches `f (Mu f)`'s kind (`*`).
So

`f` has kind `* -> *`.

Combining this with the known kind of `Mu f`, (`*`), we get the kind of the type constructor.

`Mu` has kind `(* -> *) -> *`.